# How to make the dialog box stay until explicitly dismissed?

Tags: android

I have working on an user authentication scenario.I have placed the crux of the code below.

I am calling the function

`showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);` from the onCreate() function of my activity.My problem is that the the Dialog box dismisses itself after executing the code inside any of the button click.But I want the dialog box to stay until i mention it to be dismissed.For eg:If the authetication fails I want the dialog box not to be dismissed.How can this be done?

```
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                switch (id) {

                case DIALOG_LOGIN:
                    // Inflating the View from the xml
                    factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                    loginView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);

                    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_login)
                            .setView(loginView)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                            Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                                                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs
                                                    .edit();

                                            EditText username = (EditText) loginView
                                                    .findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
                                            EditText password = (EditText) loginView
                                                    .findViewById(R.id.password_edit);

                                            //Authenticating UserName and Password.
                                            String params [] ={username.getText().toString(),
                                                               password.getText().toString()};
                                            new AsyncAuthneticationTask().execute(params);


                                        }
                                    })

    .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel,
                                new OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    }
                                }).create();
}

        return null;
    }
```

OnPostExecute function of the Async Task:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response){


        Toast toast;
        if(response.contains("Invalid")){
            toast=Toast.makeText(Login.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

        }
        else{
            toast=Toast.makeText(Login.this, getString(R.string.authentication_success_msg), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

avoid .setPositiveButton and use a custom interface instad, the are you able to dismiss the Dialog whenever you want

Samplecode withut custom controls

```
             LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(tab3.this);
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab3.this);
             builder.setTitle(params[4]);
             View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.xml.dialog_addr, null);

             final EditText et_city = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_1);
             final EditText et_street = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_2);
             final EditText et_number = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_et_3);
             ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tv_1)).setText(R.string.dialog_city);
             ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tv_2)).setText(R.string.dialog_street);
             ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tv_3)).setText(R.string.dialog_number);


             builder.setView(convertView);
             final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
             et_city.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (hasFocus) {
                            alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }); 
             alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a While loop containing the whole dialog:

```
boolean success = false;
...
case DIALOG_LOGIN:
    do
    {
    ...
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            ...
            success=true;
        }
        ...
    }while (!success)
```

Comment: Strange construction to have the do/while loop continuously set an OnClickListener. :o

Comment: haha yeah but if it worked that would seem easier than writing a custom interface/dialog. also from what i understand, it shouldn't be a problem with the listeners since they get thrown away when the dialog disappears. i could be totally wrong, thats just what i would try first.

Comment: Nah I think you're correct on that topic, but I'm not sure either :o

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is the default behaviour of the Dialog class for Android. If you want to explicitly make it stay, I think you need to create your own Dialog window, for which you can define the behaviour yourself. For examples just google it.

Comment: Never thought I needed to create a custom Dialog class for this.Hasn't anybody else faced this kind of need.

Comment: Well actually, if you look at your own edit, you gave the answer yourself if I'm not mistaken. Read user590849's answer again and look at the onPostExecute method. It will run through the code in the else clause which in turn closes the dialog. I don't know if this is the behaviour you want it to have, but this might cause it.

Comment: Nope.I was trying different ways there.The dialog will be dismissed as soon as the code execution is over.

Comment: Well, in response to my original answer, take a look at http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application. It shows how you can create your own dialog in which you can specify the behaviour. It is actually just as simple as adding another Activity (as it is just adding another Activity).

Comment: Well, I was mistaken, not another Activity. But fairly simple nontheless

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand why you are calling

dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);

showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);

one after the other? i mean you don't need to do that. Just don't do anything when the user presses the negetive button. Or just close the dialog.

Also the authentication seems to be done in new AsyncAuthneticationTask().execute(params);
thread. Are you by mistake closing the dialog box with the dismiss() call in the onpostexecute method in there?

Comment: I think that was an effort rogerstone undertook to solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a custom dialog would be the way to go:

```
    // UPDATE BUTTON HANDLER
    final Button buttonUpdate= (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.ButtonPasswordUpdate);
    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String entryFirst= editTextPasswordFirst.getText().toString();
            String entrySecond= editTextPasswordSecond.getText().toString();        
            if (entryFirst.equals(entrySecond)) { // do NOT use == with string values
                if (entryFirst.length() != lengthPassword) { // invalid key length
                    editTextPasswordFirst.setText("Invalid Key Length of "+
                            new Integer(entryFirst.length()).toString());                        
                    editTextPasswordSecond.setText("");
                    editTextPasswordFirst.selectAll();
                    editTextPasswordFirst.requestFocus();
                }
                else {
                    editTextPassword.setText(entryFirst);
                    // *** Clear Key Fields ***
                    editTextPasswordFirst.setText("");                   
                    editTextPasswordSecond.setText("");
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            }
            else { // entries do not match
                editTextPasswordFirst.setText("Entries did not match!");                   
                editTextPasswordSecond.setText("");
                editTextPasswordFirst.selectAll();
                editTextPasswordFirst.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

[More code here.](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/custom-password-dialog)